# Was Dweomercore created for Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage

Did Dweomercore, Halaster's magic academy in Undermountain, exist in any published Forgotten Realms lore prior to *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*? If so, where? Or was Dweomercore created for *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*?

A web search doesn't turn up much, but [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DungeonoftheMadMage/comments/bz0t3g/some_quandaries_regarding_dweomercore/) is one online post that states, "In older lore, I recall Trobriand actually set up Dweomercore..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I could not find a reference in earlier lore

I found no reference in past editions to Dweomercore prior to *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Madmage* contrary to what u/venkelos1 suggests in your linked reddit post. I checked the following sourcebooks:

#### AD&D 2e

- *Ruins of Undermountain*
- *Ruins of Undermountain II: The Deep Levels*
  (this book is where Trobriand was introduced)
- *Skullport*
- *Undermountain: Maddgoth's Castle*
- *Undermountain: Stardock*
- *Undermountain: The Lost Level*

#### D&D 3.xe

- *Expedition to Undermountain*

#### D&D 4e

- *Halls of Undermountain*
- *Undermountain: Halaster's Lost Apprentice*

...and the following video games:

- *Descent to Undermountain*
- *Neverwinter Nights: Hordes of the Underdark*
- *Neverwinter Online: Module 16 and 17*

All that being said, I may have overlooked a reference, or Dweomercore may have appeared in a source that I don't have access to, including one of the various novels whose stories involve Undermountain, or any of the "Dragon" magazine articles, a few of which certainly  reference Undermountain (i.e. see the below quote from *Skullport*).

> Some further information about Skullport appeared in DRAGON® magazine, and eventually the scanty information about it was brought together, slightly expanded, and updated in the City of Splendors boxed set.